# Auto complete in text field in odoo

Tags: autocomplete, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to select a customer from the select box by start typing its phone number.

How can I do that?

I have seen some are using name_search method.But still i am confused how to use it in both front end and back end.

Or is there any other solution for this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `name_search` method of your model and the domain you want on the `args` variable. Take a look at `addons/account/account.py` around line 595 `args += [('type', '=', type)]` for a concrete implementation. Make sure that you return the appropriate data structure as documented in the method's docstring at `openerp/models.py`.

Answer (score 1):

For Auto complete in odoo. It provides suggestion only in case of using Many2one field in any module.

If you want to show suggestion and autocomplete. Create a model to store the mobile numbers and then use that particular model  as foreign key in existing model.

That will do for you.